# CSS Horizontal scroll problem

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling

**Problem**

[image]
[image]

I need the content to force to scroll on X axis, not down the Y axis.

**HTML**

I know this is formatted badly but it's dynamically generated and has no white space.

```
<div class="folderWrapper" id="folderContainer"><div class="folderBox ui-droppable folderBoxSel" onclick="folderSelected(0)" id="fBox0"><div class="counter" id="fCount0">4</div><div class="folderName">Unsorted</div></div><div class="folderBox ui-droppable" onclick="folderSelected(1)" id="fBox1"><div class="counter" id="fCount1">0</div><div class="folderName">test</div></div><div class="folderBox" onclick="folderSelected(1)" id="fBox1"><div class="counter" id="fCount1">0</div><div class="folderName">test</div></div><div class="folderBox" onclick="folderSelected(1)" id="fBox1"><div class="counter" id="fCount1">0</div><div class="folderName">test</div></div><div class="folderBox" onclick="folderSelected(1)" id="fBox1"><div class="counter" id="fCount1">0</div><div class="folderName">test</div></div><div class="folderBox" onclick="folderSelected(1)" id="fBox1"><div class="counter" id="fCount1">0</div><div class="folderName">test</div></div></div>
```

Formatted nicely with one folder inner box:

```
<div class="folderWrapper" id="folderContainer">
    <div class="folderBox ui-droppable folderBoxSel" onclick="folderSelected(0)" id="fBox0">
        <div class="counter" id="fCount0">4</div>
        <div class="folderName">Unsorted</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.folderWrapper{
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    height:85px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.folderBox{
    float:left;
    background-image:url(../images/artworking/folder.png);
    background-position:center top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:85px;
    height:55px;  
    position:relative;
    padding:5px;
    z-index:4;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.folderBox:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thanks if anyone can help!

**Edit**

Bazzz's answer works in all browsers except IE compatability mode (unfortunatly it has to be compatible) which gives the following look:

[image]

With IE hack:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `inline-block` on your folderBox instead of `float:left`

```
.folderBox{
    float: left; /* remove this line */
    display: inline-block; /* add this line */
}
```

whitespace: no-wrap doesn't work on floated elements, it works on inline elements.

For IE 7 I found a little hack that might help you out:

http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

try this css:

```
.folderBox{
 display: inline-block;
 zoom: 1;
 *display: inline;
 }
```

**Most recent edit:**

This css works in IE 8 compat mode (IE7 standard):

```
.folderWrapper{
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height:85px;
    width: 300px; /* not really your css, I used it in my test case */
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.folderBox{
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    background-image:url(../images/artworking/folder.png);
    background-position:center top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:85px;
    height:55px;  
}
```

I believe the non-overflowing problem in IE7 lies in the `position:relative` that you use. I removed it, and some other css and now it works.

Comment: Sorry Baz had to remove it, in IE compatability mode it's showing up really funky ill update the question to show

Comment: IE older than 8 doesn't support `inline-block` well. If you need it to work in IE 7 and earlier you can use your `float:left` but then you have to define a width for the folderWrapper so that the floating elements do not go to the next line. If the number of folders is not static then providing this width is not so easy. Alternatively you can make the folderBox a `span` instead of `div`, I'm not sure whether that will give the correct result, but it's worth a try.

Comment: also note that `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are not well supported by IE 7 and older. I believe `overflow` is, but then it will likely give a horizontal as well as a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks, the hack -sort of works- but it's not hiding the contents horizontally, all the folders are displaying outside the scroll area.  But you've given me some other things to work with, thanks.  Godamn IE has wasted so much of our lives.

Comment: Hahaha, indeed I would vote for the one who abolishes IE7 (and in particular IE6) by law. Can you update your question with some new screenshots, or perhaps your current code? I feel we are close to a working solution and, am also interested in finding the answer that works on IE7.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for your help, appreciate it tons!  I've put a new screenshot in which uses your CSS hack, it works fine in all browsers except IE compat which the SS is showing.  As you can see they are flowing outside the container div, the scrollbar is sort of functional in moving them all across but just not hiding them.

Comment: Tom, have a look at my most recent edit, I believe it is a working solution. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I would create HTML like:

```
<div id="folderWrapper">
     <ul id="folderList">
         <li class="folderBox">...</li>
         <li class="folderBox">...</li>
         <li class="folderBox">...</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#folderWrapper {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    width:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#folderList {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    width:20000px;
}
.folderBox {
    float:left;
}
```

and then use a jquery based scrollbar inside #folderWrapper:
http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/

I like jScrollPane.